# Missing time component in dateCreated for objects of one particular domain class

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

In our Grails app we have a particular domain class whose auto-generated `dateCreated` value is sometimes wrong.  The saved datetime in the database contains a year, month, and date, but is missing the hour, minute, and second.  The domain class is defined like so:

```
class Monster {
    // ...various other fields, but no hibernate hooks, or anything clever like that
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated
}
```

It's backed by a table in a MySQL database, in a column `date_created` with type `datetime`.  The column is not-null but has no other constraints, triggers, or such.

About one in six Monsters are affected, with no pattern we've yet discerned.  We don't ever set `dateCreated` explicitly, never anywhere in our application code.  `lastUpdated` on Monster is always complete, and `dateCreated` is fine on all our domain objects except for Monster.

Do these symptoms suggest anything to anybody?  We started with the assumption that we were writing to it ourselves in some dumb way, but we've been searching for days and have  yet to find anything even vaguely suggestive.

Comment: That is almost not possible, but apparently it is happening.  Are you validating the value by looking in the database directly or just based on what you are seeing in the Grails app?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Alas, we see these bad values both in the database and in our reconstituted objects.

Comment: Do you have code anywhere in your app which assigns a value to dateCreated?

Comment: Peculiar indeed.  If you can figure out a way to make it happen, please file a JIRA and we will straighten it out.  This is the first I have heard of this.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown we don't set dateCreated directly anywhere in the app, not on any domain object.  We're now looking at indirect accesses--perhaps somewhere we write `monster."$it" = a-date-without-a-time-component` without meaning to?  But I'm not optimistic.  If we manage to distil a repro I'll be sure to file it.

Comment: One thing that might help is to remove the property and then run your app.  If there is code somewhere assigning a value, that could cause an exception and you would know where it was coming from.  Just a thought.